# MySQL distinct values across columns

Tags: mysql, distinct, multiple-columns

I have the following table:

```
id    lb     rb     ls     rs     ch     bk     ot
 1  10000  10001  10001  10001  10001  10001  10000
 2      0  10000      0  10001      0  10000      0
 3      0      0  10000  10001  10000      0      0
 4      0      0      0  10000      0      0      0
 5      0      0      0  10000      0      0      0
```

I want to be able to get the total distinct values across all columns (excluding 0) so the result is as such:

```
Code   Qty
10000    8
10001    7
```

What's the easiest/best way to do this?

Thanks, Stu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
SELECT col1, COUNT(*)
FROM
  (
  SELECT lb AS col1
  FROM table
    UNION ALL 
  SELECT rb
  FROM table
    UNION ALL ... etc
  ) a
WHERE col1 != 0
GROUP BY col1
```

Instead of  `WHERE col1 != 0` you can add `WHERE field_name !=0`  to each `SELECT` in `UNION`

Comment: I'm afraid that's throwing the error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') WHERE col1 != 0 GROUP BY col1' `

Comment: I think it might have something to do with the ")a". I don't really understand why the a... Try removing it. Id this still doesn't work you can show your full query?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT code     AS Code
     , SUM(cnt) AS Qty
FROM
  (   SELECT lb AS code
           , COUNT(*) AS cnt
      FROM TableX
      GROUP BY lb        
  UNION ALL
      SELECT rb AS code
           , COUNT(*) AS cnt
      FROM TableX
      GROUP BY rb
  UNION ALL        
    ...
  UNION ALL
      SELECT ot AS code
           , COUNT(*) AS cnt
      FROM TableX
      GROUP BY ot
  ) AS tmp
GROUP BY code
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting `Every derived table must have its own alias` error with this :(

Comment: Try now. I've added parenthesis in the correct place. The only thing I haven't put is the `WHERE col <> 0`